# Service variables being reset when manually typing in a route

Tags: angular

I have no clue what's going on. I'm building a site in Angular 4. I have created a service (Singleton) with user information stored inside (username, email etc). 
this get's displayed on the profile page.

When i go to the '/profile' route by clicking an anchor tag (with Routerlink) it goes to the profile page, and displays the user info (from the service) without a problem. However, when i manually type in the url 'Localhost:4200/profile' it goes to the profile page, but all the fields that are supposed to show the user info, are empty. (the values are  null).

Is there an Angular mechanic that i'm missing here? why is this happening? 
what's the difference between manually typing in a url and getting there via a routerlink?

User.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  public username;
  public role;
  public token;
  public firstname;
  public lastname;
  public organisation_id;
  private profilePicture = '../../assets/Images/No_user_image.jpg';


  constructor() { }


    clearUser() {
    this.username = null;
    this.role = null;
    this.token = null;
    this.firstname = null;
    this.lastname = null;
    this.organisation_id = null;
  }

}
```

App.module.ts (i've added the user service to the providers here, to make it a singleton instance)

```
// Imports
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {NgxPaginationModule} from 'ngx-pagination';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import { NgxDatatableModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable';

// Components
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ContentComponent } from './content/content.component';
import { OrganisationComponent } from './organisation/organisation.component';
import { LicenseComponent } from './license/license.component';
import { MainMenuComponent } from './main-menu/main-menu.component';
import { LogsComponent } from './logs/logs.component';
import { CommunityComponent } from './community/community.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './auth/signup/signup.component';
import { SigninComponent } from './auth/signin/signin.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { LandingPageComponent } from './landing-page/landing-page.component';

// Services
import { AuthGuard } from './auth/auth-guard.service';
import { GlobalService } from './global.service';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { UserService } from './auth/user.service';
import { DatabaseApiService } from './api/database-api.service';
import { ContentDetailComponent } from './content-detail/content-detail.component';
import { XdashtableComponent } from './xdashtable/xdashtable.component';
import { EditableFieldComponent } from './editable-field/editable-field.component';
import { AdminPanelComponent } from './admin-panel/admin-panel.component';
import { AccessDeniedComponent } from './access-denied/access-denied.component';



// If all roles can access a route, do not add the data parameter.
// If a select few roles can access a route, specify them in the data parameter.
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: MainMenuComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  { path: 'Forbidden', component: AccessDeniedComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  { path: 'Content', component: ContentComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'Content/:id', component: ContentDetailComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'Organisations', component: OrganisationComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'Organisations/:id', component: OrganisationComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'Licenses', component: LicenseComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'Licenses/:id', component: LicenseComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'Logs', component: LogsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'Community', component: CommunityComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'Profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'Signup', component: SignupComponent },
  { path: 'Login', component: SigninComponent },
  { path: 'Landing', component: LandingPageComponent},
  { path: 'Adminpanel', component: AdminPanelComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], data: {roles: ['Admin', 'Head Admin']}},
  { path: '**', component: MainMenuComponent , canActivate: [AuthGuard]}, // Page not Found
];





@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ContentComponent,
    OrganisationComponent,
    LicenseComponent,
    MainMenuComponent,
    LogsComponent,
    CommunityComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    SigninComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    LandingPageComponent,
    ContentDetailComponent,
    XdashtableComponent,
    EditableFieldComponent,
    AdminPanelComponent,
    AccessDeniedComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgxPaginationModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    NgxDatatableModule,

  ],
  providers: [GlobalService, AuthGuard, AuthService, UserService, DatabaseApiService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Profile.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from "../auth/user.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

Comment: may you share your code here...

Comment: it shouldn't be different if you route to the `profile` by link or directly by url, the `angular DI` provice new instance from `UserService` if it's NOT being created before (singleton) .. i think in some how you are updating `UserService` properties before you route to `profile` by clicking on link...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data stored in service memory is temporary and is lost on refresh. When you route to profile page manually the data is lost as the route gets refreshed.

To avoid this you have many options.

1] implement some server side functionality so that you fetch the data on route navigation.

2] use browser local storage to store the data and retrieve from the local storage as per you requirement.

The standard [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

An [example](https://github.com/marcj/angular2-localstorage) with angular

Comment: As the user component stores some sensitive information, such as the user's role and JSON web token (used for API calls), i think localstorage is not a good option, as the user would be able to edit this (right?).

Comment: you can encrypt the token and store it.

Comment: For added security you can also use sessionStorage